# Keep on getting "Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument" error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using v5.0 of Facebook's PHP SDK and have already set up an app.

I would like to get a list of friends via the Graph API using the SDK. To illustrate my implementation, this is the code in which I am trying to get lists of friends on Facebook:

```
public static function getFriends($access_token)
{
    $facebook_app_id = env('FACEBOOK_APP_ID');
    $facebook_app_secret = env('FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET');
    $facebook = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => $facebook_app_id,
        'app_secret' => $facebook_app_secret,
        'default_access_token' => $access_token,
        'default_graph_version' => env('FACEBOOK_API_VERSION') // v2.7
    ]);

    try {
        $facebook_request = $facebook->get('me/taggable_friends');
        $friends = $facebook_request->getGraphEdge();
        $all_friends = $friends->asArray();

        if ($facebook->next($friends)) {
            while ($friends = $facebook->next($friends)) {
                $all_friends = array_merge($friends->asArray(), $all_friends);
            }
        }

        return $all_friends;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

When the above method is called, it shows a `Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument` exception message. Digging around, I [read](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests) that passing a separate parameter of `appsecret_proof` will get rid of this, however, I've already tried using the `App Token` of my app taken from the `Access Token Tool` page to get the value for the `appsecret_proof` and I still get the error.

And to add, the `Require App Secret` in my app settings is set to `No` and yet I still get the same error. Am I missing anything or am I passing the wrong values in getting `appsecret_proof`?

Comment: The PHP SDK sends the app-secret proof automatically. Please double-check your app id and secret (most often such problems are caused by one of those being wrong.)

Comment: Yes, I've checked them (in fact lots of times already) and it seems this error persists.

Comment: Please any solution ?